# What does "Where C is given by ||z|| = 2 " mean?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have the integral

\begin{equation}
\oint_C \frac{\cosh z}{z^5}dz
\end{equation}
where $C$ is given by $C=\{z:|z|=2\}$

What is does this mean? How is the integral being bounded?

Comment: It is bounded by a circle of radius 2.

Comment: You are integrating your function on the circle of radius $2$. Which means you can write $z=2e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying $C=\{z:|z|=2\}$ is imprecise. Orientation of the circle also matters. What is inteded is likely to be the integral over the path $\gamma$ defined by $\gamma (t)=2e^{2\pi i t}, 0 \leq  t \leq 1$, the positively oriented circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is bounded by the circumference of a circle on the complex plane.

The circle's center point is at (0,0), and its radius is equal to |z|.